# Can I transfer my Windows Phone and Windows 8 App from one account to another?

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Can I transfer my windows 8 and windows phone apps from one developer account to another?

App includes paid and free version. I want to transfer apps and later I will delete it from old account.

Will my payment option will also be updated as per new account for paid apps?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for Windows Phone this doesn't seem to be an option for the time being - you would have to completely republish the app from the new account - see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpregister/thread/97446550-3bdd-4ad5-886d-d27aed1ffca1/ and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpregister/thread/5a9db60a-0145-4b42-b9e3-d0a92c5d3608/

Comment: so it is possible for windows 8 but not for windows phone even windows phone 8 as the store account will be same for both. Is It?

Comment: Unfortunately apps cannot be transferred between Developer accounts for Windows 8 or Windows Phone 8... the only option Microsoft suggests is to unpublish on your original account and then republish on the new account (which would remove the statistics and the update cycle)

Comment: Do you specifically need to change the e-mail address associated with the account? An account can only be associated with one Live ID, and if you need to migrate to a different ID you can't do anything. However if you only wanted to, for example, change your account name, you could do that separately

Comment: if we republish once again on new account we will loose all statistics all collected, download, votes etc.

Comment: I want to migrate apps to totally different account.

Comment: According to Microsoft Representatives there is currently no way to migrate apps from one account to another different account, so your only option, if you *must* switch account, is to lose all your statistics and start fresh

Comment: I don't know about moving Win 8 app from one account to another, but I do know that you can change publisher id, since we had to do it. Took about 6 weeks.

Answer (score 6):

Right now, only Windows Phone app can be migrated to other account.
You have to open a support ticket to Microsoft. It can be done via help of support staff.

1) Sign in to [Windows Phone Dev Center](https://dev.windowsphone.com/) or W[indows Store Dev Center](http://dev.windows.com) with the account that currently owns the app you want to transfer

2) Submit a [support ticket](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=293697)

3) Write that you want to move the app from one account to another, and include all relevant information

4) The process can take up to a week (officially; my app was moved in a few hours

5) That’s it – app is moved to another account: all stats, downloads and reviews are preserved!

Comment: No it can only be done for Windows Phone Dev Center app but not for Windows Store Dev Center app.